# Dynamic selects from pre-loaded data gives 'java.util.Vector' error

Tags: android, odk

Collect v1.7.1 Android v5.1.1, device used - Redmi 2s

I am trying to preload data from a csv file into a select box dynamically.
I created the XLSForm as guided here - http://xlsform.org/#dynamic-selects-from-pre-loaded-data
But on running it on the ODK Collect it gives an error saying,

"The search handler returned a object of type 'java.util.Vector'."

I have looked online but got no idea of how to solve this and not able to find any solution.
Please help!

This is the XLSform and the csv file that I am trying to work with -

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Y0vW0cjl1nbkZczXRmcTC71Pso8dRbouPSYWGBdvBWU/edit#gid=2073943561

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gprb7ocTYlT_seOBFY5CuoxyodcXwWOuVxmp38OX1dE/edit#gid=1405027019

Comment: You might want to post some code.

Comment: @shmosel I have updated my question with the files that I am using.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] and paste the entire error message here. For more tips on improving your question to attract the answer you are looking for, read [ask].

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I did post a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example which are - one XLS form and one csv file.
I also have pasted the error as it is in my question.

Comment: Please post all necessary information here directly. Links can become out of date which will make this question useless for anyone else who encounters the same problem in the future.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice For XLSForm there is no need to write any java code. We just have to create an excel file which is converted into XML and that XML is uploaded in ODK Collect along with the csv and then the form is available.

Comment: I removed the Java tag since this does not have anything to do with Java.